# How to mock CActiveRecord of Yii@1.1 with phpunit (avoid nulled properties)?

Tags: php, yii, mocking, phpunit

A legacy project uses Yii@1.1. Its database entities are instances of `CActiveRecord`.

Assume I have a model called `User` having the properties `id`, `firstname`, and `lastname`.

In a service `DoSomethingWithUser`, I access the entity read-only:

```
class DoSomethingWithUser {
    public function doSth(User $user) {
        $id = $user->id;
        $name = $user->name;
        $lastname = $user->lastname;

        ...

        return $result;
    }
}
```

In the testcase for the service, I want to inject a mock of the `CActiveRecord`, so I naively thought I could do something like this:

```
class DoSomethingWithUserTest extends TestCase
    testdoSth() {
        /**
         * @var User|MockObject $user
         */

        $user = $this->createMock(User::class);
        $user->id = 23;
        $user->lastname = "LAST_NAME";
        $user->firstname = "FIRST_NAME";

        $actualResult = (new DoSomethingWithUser())->doSth($user);
        
        $this->assertSame($expectedResult, $actualResult);
    }
```

I also tried going by `setAttributes`:

```
 $user->setAttributes(
     ['id' => 23, 'firstname'  => 'FIRST NAME', 'lastname' => 'LAST NAME']
 );
```

without success.

As during test-runtime, those properties are always `null`.

I assume it has to do with the magic getters of a `CActiveRecord` yet I have no clue how to go about it.

How do I mock the attributes of a `CActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 0):

By accident I found out that doing:

```php
$user = $this->createMock(User::class);
$user->setMethods(['attributes'])
$user->id = 23;
$user->lastname = "LAST_NAME";
$user->firstname = "FIRST_NAME";
```

works as expected. Though I don't know why.